# Save image dimensions in state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my React.js application, I'm rendering a PNG image. From there, I'm going to render an interactive SVG directly on top of the image. In this case, it's important that the SVG always be the same size as the PNG.

I'm currently solving this problem by storing the image dimensions in state, and using an `onLoad` function to capture the image dimensions when the PNG loads. I'm then passing the dimensions to my SVG as props. Here's my current code:

```js
export default function MyComponent() {
   const [imageHeight, setImageHeight] = useState(0);
   const [imageWidth, setImageWidth] = useState(0);

   const getImageDimensions = (event) => {
     setImageWidth(event.target.offsetWidth);
     setImageHeight(event.target.offsetHeight);
     return;
   };

   return(
     <img
       onLoad={getImageDimensions}
       src={imageSource}
     />
     <InteractiveSvg
       width={imageWidth}
       height={imageHeight}
     />
   );
}
```

This solves the problem in most cases. However, I run into an issue whenever the PNG is resized (such as when the user resizes the window). When this happens, `imageHeight` and `imageHeight` aren't reset to account for the new image dimensions. I tried adding an `onChange` function to the `<img/>` tag, but that didn't solve the problem.

How can I set a watch for my image's size changing? Alternatively, is there a more elegant way to ensure that my PNG and SVG are always the same size?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend, if possible, using CSS instead of useState for sizing. You can set different screen heights & widths, and change the properties dynamically.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  /* CSS that should be displayed if width is equal to or less than 800px goes here */
}
```

If you really want to implement useState, you'll want to setup an event listener in useEffect (similar to componentDidMount in class-based, if you're familiar)

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  let window_width = 0;
  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
     window_width = window.innerWidth
     // logic for imageSize state
  });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `resize` on the image or `window` global. and get image size using `useRef`

```
useEffect(() => {
  [window | imageRef].addEventListener("resize", function);
  return () => {
     [window | imageRef].removeEventListener("resize", function)
  }
}, []);
```